# Change and Remove several package by command

Tags: opensuse, rpm

I want to remove several package by using rpm -qa --last to check, i afraid doing wrongly and crash the system.

**Question:**

I have installed pcsc tool for two installation in one system, how to set the pcsc-tools to **1.5.2**  before remove them?

Is there a way to display the list inside **rpm -qa --last > list**?

**Command check pcsc version:**

pcscd -fd

**Current running pcsc:**

1. **00000000** pcscdaemon.c:280:main() pcscd set to foreground with debug send to stderr
2. **00000029** debuglog.c:239:DebugLogSetLevel() debug level=debug
3. **00000619** pcscdaemon.c:498:main() pcsc-lite 1.4.102 daemon ready.
4. **00000497** hotplug_libhal.c:450:HPRegisterForHotplugEvents() No     bundle files in pcsc drivers directory: /usr/lib64/readers
5. **00000008** hotplug_libhal.c:451:HPRegisterForHotplugEvents() Disabling USB support for pcscd
6. **00000006**  pcscdaemon.c:517:main() SVCServiceRunLoop returned
7. **00000005**  pcscdaemon.c:523:at_exit() cleaning /var/run/pcscd

   **Command and Result update:**

   zypper se -s pcsc

> ```
> S | Name            | Type    | Version         | Arch   | Repository
> --+-----------------+---------+-----------------+--------+------------------
> i | pcsc-lite       | package | 1.4.102-1.37.3  | x86_64 | (System Packages)
> i | pcsc-lite-32bit | package | 1.4.102-1.37.3  | x86_64 | (System Packages)
> i | pcsc-tools      | package | 1.5.2-lp150.1.3 | x86_64 | (System Packages)
> ```

cat /etc/os-release

```
NAME="Vet" 
VERSION="11.4" 
VERSION_ID="11.4" 
PRETTY_NAME="SUSE Linux Enterprise Server 11 SP4" 
ID="vet" 
ANSI_COLOR="0;32"
CPE_NAME="cpe:/o:suse:sles:11:4"
```

zypper lr -d

```
# | Alias                                                                  | Name                                                                 | Enabled | Refresh | Priority | Type  | URI                                                                     | Service
--+------------------------------------------------------------------------+----------------------------------------------------------------------+---------+---------+----------+-------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------+--------
1 | SUSE-Linux-Enterprise-High-Availability-Extension-11-SP4_11.4.4-1.54   | SUSE-Linux-Enterprise-High-Availability-Extension-11-SP4 11.4.4-1.54 | Yes     | No      |   99     | yast2 | iso:///?iso=SLE-HA-11-SP4-x86_64-GM-CD1.iso&url=file:///home/source/    |
2 | SUSE-Linux-Enterprise-High-Availability-Extension-11-SP4_11.4.4-1.54_1 | SUSE-Linux-Enterprise-High-Availability-Extension-11-SP4 11.4.4-1.54 | Yes     | No      |   99     | yast2 | iso:///?iso=SLE-HA-11-SP4-x86_64-GM-CD2.iso&url=file:///home/source/    |
3 | SUSE-Linux-Enterprise-Server-11-SP4_11.4.4-1.109                       | SUSE-Linux-Enterprise-Server-11-SP4 11.4.4-1.109                     | Yes     | No      |   99     | yast2 | iso:///?iso=SLES-11-SP4-DVD-x86_64-GM-DVD1.iso&url=file:///home/source/ |
```

zypper lr

```
       # | Alias                                                                  | Name                                                                 | Enabled | Refresh
     --+------------------------------------------------------------------------+----------------------------------------------------------------------+---------+-------- 
     1 | SUSE-Linux-Enterprise-High-Availability-Extension-11-SP4_11.4.4-1.54   | SUSE-Linux-Enterprise-High-Availability-Extension-11-SP4 11.4.4-1.54 | Yes     | No 
     2 | SUSE-Linux-Enterprise-High-Availability-Extension-11-SP4_11.4.4-1.54_1 | SUSE-Linux-Enterprise-High-Availability-Extension-11-SP4 11.4.4-1.54 | Yes     | No 
     3 | SUSE-Linux-Enterprise-Server-11-SP4_11.4.4-1.109    | SUSE-Linux-Enterprise-Server-11-SP4 11.4.4-1.109                     | Yes     | No 
     4 | pcsc-repo                                           | pcsc-repo          | Yes     | No
```

zypper se -s pcsc-lite

```
S | Name            | Type    | Version        | Arch   | Repository
--+-----------------+---------+----------------+--------+------------------
i | pcsc-lite       | package | 1.4.102-1.37.3 | x86_64 | (System Packages)
i | pcsc-lite-32bit | package | 1.4.102-1.37.3 | x86_64 | (System Packages)
```

zypper ref

```
Retrieving repository 'SUSE-Linux-Enterprise-High-Availability-Extension-11-SP4 11.4.4-1.54' metadata [error]
Repository 'SUSE-Linux-Enterprise-High-Availability-Extension-11-SP4 11.4.4-1.54' is invalid.
[|] Valid metadata not found at specified URL(s)
Please check if the URIs defined for this repository are pointing to a valid repository.
Skipping repository 'SUSE-Linux-Enterprise-High-Availability-Extension-11-SP4 11.4.4-1.54' because of the above error.
Retrieving repository 'SUSE-Linux-Enterprise-High-Availability-Extension-11-SP4 11.4.4-1.54' metadata [|]
Specified path '/home/source/' is not a directory: file:/home/source/
```

**Below are the packages to be removed:**

1. pcsc-lite 1.4.102
2. pcsc-tools-1.5.2-lp150.1.3

Comment: For openSUSE systems I would recommend to use `zypper`, it can be compared to `yum` and is the package management system. With zypper you can see what dependencies a package has when you install it or which other packages will be deleted with `zypper rm <package>`. To force a specific version of a package you can run `zypper in -f <package_name>=<version>`. To list all available versions of a package run `zypper se -s <package>`. But I don't fully understand your question. You want pcs-tools in version 1.5.2 and then remove it? The package has already version 1.5.2 according to your output.

Comment: Also removing single rpm's is very dangerous, I would not recommend that unless you really know what you're doing, and not without a backup. Maybe you could explain more clearly what exactly you need to do.

Comment: @eblock i have installed two different version of pscs in one system, i would like to try to change current 1.4 version to 1.5 , is there anyway can change this?

Comment: pcsc-lite and pcsc-tools are obviously two different packages, I'm not sure if you are confusing things. Do you need pcsc-lite with version 1.5, is that what you're asking? Could you add the output of `zypper se -s pcsc` to your question?

Comment: @eblock i have update the question by using the command you ask.

Comment: Alright, it seems as if you don't have repositories configured that contain pcsc-lite 1.5. Which distro of openSUSE are you running? I can't even find such an old version on https://software.opensuse.org/package/pcsc-lite?search_term=pcsc-lite. Can you also share `cat /etc/os-release` if that's present, and if not please run `cat /etc/SuSE-release`. Did you install the rpm's manually and not from a repository?

Comment: @eblock i have update the question, is an old version opensuse, i need to find third party support to install pcsc tool

Comment: So this is not openSUSE but SLES. If it's a registered system you should be subscribed to the SLES 11 repos, can you show the output of `zypper lr -d`? For SUSE products you can also ask in the respective [SUSE forums](https://forums.suse.com/forumdisplay.php?8-SUSE-Linux-Enterprise-Server).

Comment: @eblock i have update the question

Answer (score 0):

The installation transaction can be undone by doing "sudo yum history list" and identifying the transaction number. It can be undone by "sudo yum history undo transaction_number".

This might not be the right thing to do if there were other packages installed together with pcsc* packages as it will remove them too.

The best thing to do would be removing the packages with "rpm -e --nodeps pcsc-lite 1.4.102 pcsc-tools-1.5.2-lp150.1.3" to remove the packages without removing any dependencies needed by other applications.

If you have the possibility of doing a snapshot, it is better to take one just in case.

Comment: i would like to try to change the current version from 1.4 to 1.5 is there any way to change it before remove them?

Comment: I would suggest verifying if alternatives are available for the the packages using "alternatives --config pcsc". I have never used this package but if the service is started by systemd or init scripts, you need to verifiy if the proper binary has been defined. I would suggest doing a "which pcsc" and doing an ls -lh "path of pcsc" to see if there is a link pointing on the correct version. If it is not, you  can correct the link.

Comment: i have update the question feel free to take a look thank you

Answer (score 0):

Add the following repo to the system by running:

```
# add repo
zypper addrepo https://download.opensuse.org/repositories/security:/chipcard/SLE_11_SP4/ pcsc-repo

# refresh repos
zypper ref

zypper se -s pcsc-lite
```

If the repo contains all dependencies (it's not an official repo) you should see a newer version. Install it by running `zypper in pcsc-lite=1.5.4`. You'll probably have to trust the repo at least temporarily during repo refresh to be able to use it, please do so at your own risk, I'm not aware of your security policies regarding external repositories etc.

Comment: i get an warning or error here by using zypper ref  [ Specified path '/home/source/' is not a directory: file:/home/source/]

Comment: You could disable the previously configured repos temporarily with `zypper mr -d <repo>`, or remove them completely if they aren't available anyway with `zypper rr <repo>`. Then retry the `zypper ref` command.

Comment: i have this error -bash: syntax error near unexpected token `newline' during using zypper mr -d <repo> or zypper rr <repo>

Comment: I'm not sure if I misunderstand, but you did replace '<repo>' with the respective repos, didn't you? Please add once again your current repositories to this question: `zypper lr`

Comment: i have update the question, it won't allow me to installed it while use zypper ref command , i have use zypper mr -d pcsc-repo to to change enable from yes to no and retry the zypper ref command again it get the error

Comment: The ISOs aren't available at the mentioned directory `/home/source`. You can try the following: delete the repos 1 to 3 `zypper rr 1 2 3`, just to make sure only one valid repo is present (pcsc-lite). You can add the ISO contents again after your installation worked, but make sure you have a proper directory and moint point. Do you have still access to the ISOs?

Comment: @edblock the iso file is still needed but i afraid i remove it and will be a problem to add it back again

Comment: Then you should make sure that it's properly mounted. Is the mentioned directory present? Is the ISO mounted?

Comment: Is not mount, it only show on the list

Comment: @edblock  i get an error for running zypper ref Download (curl) error for 'https://download.opensuse.org/repositories/security:/chipcard/SLE_11_SP4/repodata/repomd.xml':

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/90303/discussion-between-eblock-and-victor).

Comment: @edblock i can't download from the link you provide , it say server download error, i have download the file and move the file to the SLES, i try to use ./install-sh to install the package, it show this error message ./install-sh: no input file specified.